# React onKeyPress Render Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I'm attempting to make a component which acts as a sort of bullet list. There's an input field held in an unordered list item (acting as the first bullet point, which by default will always be there). The field has an `onKeyPress` function that checks whether or not the user presses the return (or Enter) key to create a new bullet point. When that happens, the function adds another identical input field to the `bulletList` array, which is then rendered on the page using the `.map()` JS function.

The issue I'm having is the following: On the default (first) input field that is always there, the enter functionality works perfectly. The user can press enter, and a new input field is created below it. The problem happens here: On the second (newly-created) input field, the enter functionality partly works. It logs to the console what it needs to log as a test (indicating it's being triggered) but doesn't render a new input field below. What could be the issue here? Thanks!

The original input field:

```
<input onKeyPress={(e) => handleAdd(e)} autoFocus />
```

The adder function:

```
const handleAdd = (e) => {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
            setBulletList([...bulletList, (<input onKeyPress={(e) => handleAdd(e)} autoFocus />)]);
            console.log("Worked?");
            console.log(bulletList);
        }
        
    };
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the input itself into the state? :)

Comment: @OrAssayag I'm trying to add a new input field to the array (bulletList), which renders below the original component. It works the first time, on the original one, but not in the created one right after.

Comment: I don't how it even works for the first time.

Comment: `setBulletList([...bulletList,` you need to add new item to the array, not the input itself.

Comment: @OrAssayag What I'm doing in the input field is saying: When Enter is pressed, add an input field to the bulletList array, which is rendered below the original input field.

Comment: You CAN'T insert input as HTML tags into the state. This is not how React.js works.

Comment: @OrAssayag I am adding it to the array. It's state. :) `const [bulletList, setBulletList] = useState([]);`

Comment: The array is of type ReactNode, which holds JSX elements. `const [bulletList, setBulletList] = useState<Array<React.ReactNode>>([]);`. And it does work, because it adds it once, but then it does not any more.

Comment: as @OrAssayag mentioned, you better not store JSX elements in your state. You should see what are the **states** of your component, not what it should render. You can for example store the number of your inputs, or objects containing their attributes,... . It depends on what you wanna do. But do not store JSX it probably is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have anything that differentiates the first one from the second one so React is getting confused when there's more than one. React will often warn you to make sure each element has it's own unique keys. If they don't have unique keys/identifiers then React won't update the virtual dom. The virtual dom is what React uses to identify changes that were made.

Give each one it's own class and that should work.

Comment: By class do you mean make a separate React component for each (extract it)?

Comment: I mean html class

<input className="class1">

Comment: but yes making a separate component would work to, that's often what I do when I want to do similar things. Honestly it will save you trouble down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the input value, not the input HTML tag, like this:

```
const handleAdd = (e) => {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
            setBulletList([...bulletList, e.target.value]);
            console.log("Worked?");
            console.log(bulletList);
        }
        
    };
```